# Facebook Connect PHP session variable won't set

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the Facebook PHP API 4.0 and trying to get the session variable to be set, so I can use the user's Facebook data.

The app, and Facebook approval page have all worked as expected, but the $session variable remains to be unset no matter what I try. I have tried to find the solution from similar questions on Stack with no success. This is the code I am using:

```
session_start();


//start fb login stuff
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( $config['basedir'].'/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($fb_app, $fb_secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $config['baseurl'] );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
  echo $ex;
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo $ex;
}
if ($session) {
  echo 'Session var is finally being seen';
}
//end Facebook login stuff
```

Comment: So what is in side exceptions? From your code we see that you just ignore the exceptions are thrown.

Comment: So what is the workflow? Is user redirected to you page? What exactly you do to get the expected result?

Comment: The user has to approve the app through facebook, and then they are redirected to the index page which has the above code included. Ie. they are redirected from the login page to the index page, and the index page has a config page included `require_once('config.php');` and this config page has the above code to check if the user is logged in through facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$session` remains unset because you aren't logging the user in. You should modify the last part of the code to something like:

```
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  echo 'Session var is finally being seen';
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array() ) . '">Login</a>';
}
```

If the `$session` is not set, your code will ask the user to login. After they login, the `$helper->getSessionFromRedirect();` part of your code should execute and set `$session`. [See my tutorial on how to tackle this](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).

---

**Edit**:

If you are logging the user in from a different page, you need to make sure that `$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( '{your-url}' );` is the same on both pages. If they differ, then you will get a exception from the API related to `redirect_uri mismatch`.

Comment: I didn't include the login because that code I have located on a separate login page, I assure you the user is logged in (went through the facebook approval process etc), and I have included the login as specified above on a test page as well, and I still have the same issue

Comment: Oh and I should clarify the Login link repeatedly appears on the test page

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I was under the impression, that I could use the Facebook connect API to check if the user has previously logged in using Facebook, without them needing to use the login link, is that not the case?

Comment: If you want to check if they are already logged in, the JS SDK would be more helpful. Or you can use cookies with PHP, but they would need to have used your app at lease once.